# switch back and forth between two tabs in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Are there shortcuts to go back and forth between current and last selected tab with vscode ? 
Like I used to be able to do with webstorm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This will switch between current and recent tab.

You can also switch to any of open tabs by holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly until your desired tab is highlighted from the tab selection dialog like that would appear upon first press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys,

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> would do the same but it will start navigating to the tabs from opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for this Window Switch by Victor Zhang (yeannylam). 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yeannylam.window-switch

Change extension shortcut for windowSwitch.switchToLastOpenedFile.

Answer (score 0):

If your coming from IntelliJ and you want to be able to switch tabs just like the default IntelliJ tab switcher, use these preferences:
[image: Visual Studio Keyboard Shortcuts]

The action "ctrl+tab" then "ctrl+tab" will quickly switch back and forth to the last recently used.